# How do I make my if statement more efficient?

Tags: swift, if-statement

Writing some swift code for an app and whilst it works fine, I can't help but think it's ugly and can be improved upon, I'm still new and always looking for ways to improve my code so any help is appreciated. In context it's for a slider and a couple of labels.

```
    var value1 = Int (sender.value)

    value1text.text = "\(value1)"

    var value2:Int

    if value1 <= 5 {
        endText.text = "\(7 - value1)"
    } else if value1 == 6 {
        value1 = 2
        value2 = 6
        endText.text = "\(value1)/\(value2)"
    } else if value1 == 7 {
        value1 = 2
        value2 = 5
        endText.text = "\(value1)/\(value2)"
    } else if value1 == 8 {
        value1 = 2
        value2 = 4
        endText.text = "\(value1)/\(value2)"
    } else if value1 == 9 {
        value1 = 2
        value2 = 3
        endText.text = "\(value1)/\(value2)"
    } else if value1 == 10 {
        value1 = 2
        value2 = 2
        endText.text = "\(value1)/\(value2)"
    }
```

My vars are better named in my app, just renamed for easier reading (hopefully).

Comment: Well one thing is that you are repeating `endText.text = "\(value1)/\(value2)"` each time. You could try simply putting that after the if statement is complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [`Switch` statement](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#switch).

```
var value1 = Int(sender.value) //TODO: Give me a better name!

value1text.text = String(value1) //Don't use String interpolation solely for conversion

switch (value1) {
case Int.min...5:
    endText.text = String(7 - value1)
case let x where 6...10 ~= x:
    value1 = 2
    value2 = 12 - x
    endText.text = "\(value1)/\(value2)"
default:
    fatalError("What happens now?")
}
```

Simpler/Better implementation of the second case, thanks to [Sulthan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/669586/sulthan):

```
case 6...10:
    value2 = 12 - value1
    value1 = 2
    endText.text = "\(value1)/\(value2)"
```

Comment: In the 6-10 case, this doesn't set value1 and value2 like the original does, also the original code will just do nothing to endText and the values if its outside of those ranges, it won't fatalError.

Comment: Also it misses the case for value1 = 5

Comment: Fixed both of those

Comment: I fatalError to bring it to the Author's attention. I'd rather he make the decision about default behavior over me making the assumption he intended it to do nothing

Comment: My code was wrong sorry, I've updated the values and will be sure to give them better names. :)

Comment: Is there a mathematical relationship between `value1` and the value assigned to `value2`?

Comment: @FullerPrime See my edit

Comment: that `~= x` is a bit ugly, you could just use `6...10` and then use `value2 = 12 - value1; value1 = 2`

Comment: @AMomchilov That's awesome, can't get better than that I don't think! Any chance you could take me through what's goings on here? I'm familiar with the switch statement only there's a few things that I don't quite understand. Thank you.

Comment: Can you ask concrete questions about the `few things [you] don't quite understand`?

Comment: @Sulthan What's the exact syntax you had in mind?

Comment: @Sulthan Oh I got it. I was overthinking this xD

Comment: @AMomchilov mainly `case let x where 6...10 ~= x:` I'm not sure what's going on here.

Comment: So that's a combination of a few things. First of all, the value being switch on (`value1`) is bound to the variable `x`. Then, the `where` clause is evaluated. If it's `true`, that case will be evaluated, otherwise the other cases are tested. The where clause in this case checks if x is in the range by using the `~=` operator.

Comment: Turns out most of that was unnecessary, as I could just use `value1` directly. I left my original solution for reference

Answer (score 3):

General Critiques:
`value1` and `value2` are not descriptive names really, so to make your code more readable, you could give them a more descriptive name.

Without knowing what the value variables represent, I'm not sure what the values 6 7 and 8 refer to. However, I do know that [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) also tend to make code less readable. If it makes sense for your code, consider turning those magic numbers into an [enumeration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html).

finally, you could replace a lot of the if statements with a [switch statement](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#switch)

Comment: Appreciate that, thanks. What benefits does switch offer over if? Or is it a readability thing?

Comment: More readable, probably compiles into more readable assembly (if that matters to you for some reason), has some cool advantages like handlers for switching into and out of states.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a switch statement like this, similar to AMomchilov's answer. The switch statement improves readability and makes it easier to improve upon later.

This is what your code would look like with a switch statement:

```
var value1 = Int(sender.value)

value1text.text = String(value1)

switch (value1) {

    case Int.min...5: // any value below or equal to 5
        endText.text = String(7 - value1)

    case 6...10: // between 6 and 10
        value1 = 2
        value2 = 6
        endText.text = "2/6"

    default: // else
        //do nothing
}
```

Comment: You don't need to break swift switch statements to prevent fallthrough, as they don't fallthrough by default. You do need it in cases that would otherwise be empty though

Comment: @WillM. true. Changed it

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing `value1` with `6`, `7`,`8`, `9` and `10` and doing the same stuff for all theses conditions except `value1 <= 5`.
You can shorten this code in following ways:

1. Create an dictionary with keys as `value1` and values as the one you want to replace, as `["6":"6","7":"5","8":"4","9":3,"10":"2"]`
   Check if your value contains in `keys` of `myDict`:

   ```
    var myDict = ["6":"6","7":"5","8":"4","9":3,"10":"2"]

        if value1 <= 5 {
               endText.text = "\(7 - value1)"
        } else if Array(myDict.keys).contains(String(value1)) {
               value2 = myDict[String(value1)]
               value1 = 2
               endText.text = "\(value1)/\(value2)"
        }
   ```
2. Check all values of `value1` inside a if statement:

   ```
    if value1 <= 5 {
        endText.text = "\(7 - value1)"
   }
   else if(value1 == 6 || value1 == 7 || value1 == 8 || value1 == 9 || value1 == 10) {
     value2 = myDict[String(value1)]
     value1 = 2
     endText.text = "\(value1)/\(value2)"
   }
   ```

Comment: Completely my fault but the values are actually different, I've amended the question with the correct values this time, sorry!

Comment: your `value1` is same and `value2` is changing, right?

Comment: Have modified my answer, hope this should work!